# Parse Query, How to create a query that checks if arrays contain a particular string

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using Parse.Com's backend service.

I am currently trying the code below:

I've tried a few variations and nothing seems to work. Is this even possible?

```
ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>(1);
cities.add(OriginCity);
cities.add(EndCity);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> mpassthroughcities = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ride").
whereContainsAll("Cities", cities).
whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Date", mCurrentDate);
```

After the following code runs, I use cities I know are contained within "Cities" and I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should works (see parse [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-queries-on-array-values))

Do you execute your query after ? like that:

```
mpassthroughcities.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> rides, ParseException e) {
        // check rides for results
    }
});
```

This list is empty ? Have you tried without the "whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo" ?